# Recovering partition labelled as linux swap by a deleted linux os

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, swap

Basically while installing ubuntu by  mistake  I selected one of my windows ntfs patitions as swap but i never actually booted from it as there was a problem with my boot flag at the time but I did not realised that the problem was with the boot flag at the moment so I installed another ubuntu after formatting the drive with previous ubuntu and this time i selected to install it without any swap space.I was able to boot to ubuntu and disable swap just in case but the partition is still not accessible in windows. By using paragon disk utility is saw that the partition was still marked as linux swap also I searched with gparted for the flags on the disk but there were none.

Question:  Is there a way to set the partition that was set as swap for the deleted ubuntu to be recognized by windows as a normal partition without formatting the drive?

I would also like to add that the partition is accessible in ubuntu and data is not harmed whatsoever

Comment: Once you selected (and commited) that partition for use as swap it was. formated, no turning back. Now you can only recover data using recovery tools.

Comment: You can try using testdisk to restore the old partition table. As long as the data wasn't overwritten it should be recoverable.  http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk and to recover partitions read this: http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step